# Var in python 2.7

Tags: python, variables

Hi I am having a couple of problems with my code (the variables) if anyone knows what is wrong I will be very thankful to hear what I am doing wrong with this as I have been trying for hours on end. Many thanks James.

```
    import time
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO

# Next we setup the pins for use!
GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BCM)
GPIO.setwarnings(False)
GPIO.setup(17,GPIO.OUT)
GPIO.setup(18,GPIO.OUT)

#foward, left, right

foward = print("Foward")
         GPIO.output(17, True)
         GPIO.output(18, True)
         time.sleep(3) 

left = print("Left")
       GPIO.output(17, True)
       GPIO.output(18, False)
       time.sleep(3)

Right = print("Right")
        GPIO.output(17, False)
        GPIO.output(18, True)
        time.sleep(3)


print('Starting motor sequence!')

while True:
  try:
    foward
    left
    right
    right
    right
    foward
    foward
```

Comment: That's now how you define functions and use functions.

Comment: you should read this: https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html#defining-functions

Comment: How do you do that may I ask

Comment: Have you programmed in JavaScript before? If so, that might be what is confusing you with Python functions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you are trying to make `foward`, `left`, and `right` functions. In python functions are defined like:

```
def left():
    print("Foward")
    GPIO.output(17, True)
    GPIO.output(18, True)
    time.sleep(3)
```

And called like:

```
left()
```